# No se puede ver la cobertura del código en SonarQube

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, sonarqube

quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy utilizando **Sonarqube**
para ver los errores de mi código y entre otros , el unico problema es que no se aparece la cobertura y todo esta bien y ya paso por el sonarqube y el lenguaje que estoy haciendo en .net core c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora por colocando estos comando ejecutados por el **CMD**

```
dotnet C:\sonarqube\scanner\msbuildDll\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:"PORTALSC-BACK" /d:sonar.host.url="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" /d:sonar.login="XXXXXXXXXX"

dotnet build ConsultasComerciales.sln

dotnet C:\sonarqube\scanner\msbuildDll\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end /d:sonar.login="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

si me podrían ayudar para que aparezca la cobertura que aparece 0.0%

Comment: @leandro tutini pero yo quisiera en c# .net y eso en PHP

Comment: leiste lo que explican las respuestas ? no importa el lenguaje la tool Sonarqube es la misma. Coverage se relaciona con los test que defines en el codigo, escribe y ejecuta test del codigo y tendras coverage